# How to stop a bundle in Apache Felix Webconsole using code

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

So I have these bundles installed and can be accessed through the gui from
http://localhost/path/to/bundles. Here resides the UI where one can search through the bundles and manually shut it down. I want to be able to do that in code.

I am currently looking through the org.apache.felix.webconsole-3.1.8.jar for examples. So I guess my question is:

1. How do I connect to the webconsole so that I can retrieve the list of bundles
2. How can I look for the specific bundle? By symbolicName?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code is running in the same OSGi container, there's no reason to use the webconsole for this. You can just use something like Spring-DM or Blueprint to get a reference to [BundleContext](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) and then use the getBundle methods to get a reference the bundle that you want to stop.

From there, you can call [Bundle.stop()](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#stop%28%29).

Comment: Basically correct, but easier to use a `BundleActivator` to obtain the reference to `BundleContext`.

Comment: That's often true, but, if you're already using Spring-DM or Blueprint, it's a lot easier to throw 1 extra line in an XML file than writing more code. That being said, thanks for the reminder, I'd totally forgotten about that!